# What is the difference between CFDictionaryContainsKey and CFDictionaryGetCountOfKey

Tags: objective-c, key, nsdictionary, cfdictionary

[CFDictionaryContainsKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1516808-cfdictionarycontainskey?language=objc)

[CFDictionaryGetCountOfKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1516759-cfdictionarygetcountofkey?language=objc)

It seems that they both return `1` if the key is found and `0` if not. Any difference?

Comment: Boolean vs CFIndex, that's different, no?

Comment: `'CFIndex' (aka 'long')` `'Boolean' (aka 'unsigned char')` so the difference is signedness and size?

Comment: Should I delete this post or just leave it as is?